# Can I request HR a copy of my pre-employment medical checkup?

Tags: professionalism, new-job, human-resources, health, argentina

I've recently been interviewed for employment by an IT company in this country (Argentina). Before I could be accepted for the job, they requested a pre-employment medical checkup. Today, I received a call from HR telling me that I passed it and will be starting at the new job next month.

I'm interested in getting a copy of the results from this medical checkup to show my general practitioner (GP), simply because every two years or so I have a similar checkup done privately.

**Would it be OK for me to ask HR to send me a copy of the results or would that be inappropriate?**

If it is OK, should I write them an email or wait until I start working with them?

I wouldn't want my curiosity to ruin my chances or risk anything, after all, I didn't pay for the checkup, the company did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be OK for me to ask HR to send me a copy of the results or would that be inappropriate?

**I don't see why not, or how asking this could be inappropriate.** The worst they can say is "no".

Also, writing an email or asking when you get there is up to you and if you need this information urgently or not. I don't see problem in sending a brief, polite email asking if it's possible to get the results, perhaps something in the lines of:

> Greetings [name]. I received news that my medical checkup came out all right, and was wondering if I can get a copy of the results. If possible, please tell me if you need me to provide anything else to be able to get the results. Thanks, Morgan.

You can also ask the same in person, when you start your job there, given that you could wait a month before getting the results.

As a final comment, I am not sure if giving these results to your GP will exempt you from your annual check, as sometimes physicians and medics may be a bit strict with who makes the checkups and under what standards, so it may be that your GP will insist in check you personally. However, it will be good if you manage to get the results, so you can archive them for future reference.